# git log for showing last commit

Tags: git, github

I'm adding a git log line to my deploy script:

```
git pull origin master
git log -n 1 > lastcommit.txt
ant -f build.xml deploy
```

to save details of the last commit. This produces an output file (at time of writing):

```
commit 3ced14ef1004287b55c21d384447c21cb58edfa6
Merge: 616a15e 5adc9c5
Author: www-data <www-data@backup.agilebase.co.uk>
Date:   Sat Jul 28 15:20:39 2012 +0100

Merge branch 'master' of github.com:okohll/agileBase
```

However, using that commit code https://github.com/okohll/agileBase/commits/3ced14ef1004287b55c21d384447c21cb58edfa6 returns a 404 not found error.

I must have misunderstood git log, I want to find the commit hash that will link to the last commit in github's web interface. Is there a way to do that? What does 3ced14ef1004287b55c21d384447c21cb58edfa6 refer to?

I notice that the 'Merge' line has at the end 5adc9c5 which is the start of the actual code I'm looking for, at time of writing 5adc9c51326772318394fceb479a31e26306259b.

Comment: p.s. The author of the last pushed commit is okohll, not www-data. It looks like git log is showing a local commit that hasn't been pushed yet. So the question is is there a way to get the last commit ID from master, not the local repository?

Comment: The url path part is `commit`, not `commits`, and it looks like you haven't pushed that commit back to github yet. https://github.com/okohll/agileBase/commit/3ced14ef1004287b55c21d384447c21cb58edfa6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `git pull` merged what was on github and what was in your repository into a new commit. That is `3ced14ef1004287b55c21d384447c21cb58edfa6`. This merge commit is not on github (yet). If you want to refer to that, you will need to `push` back to github.

Comment: Correct - and additionally, the URL path part is `commit`, not `commits`.

Comment: OK thanks, so how do I get the most recent merge that *is* on github?

Comment: You could do a `git fetch` and then find the hash of `origin/master` (assuming that `origin` is the remote which points to github and `master` is the branch there that you're interested in).

Comment: That seems to do it:
    'git fetch' then
    'git log --remotes -n 1'

Comment: Best you mention the exact reference rather than look for all remotes.  Also, you can use `--pretty=%H` to `git log` to get *just* the commit hash if that's all you're interested in.

Comment: i don't think it is a good idea to refer to the last commit on github when you really are compiling a completely different (local) revision. e.g. push a release to github, pull it to your local machine and start developing a totally experimental version of your software, without ever pushing back to github; `git log --remotes -n 1` will always refer to the stable tag, which has diverged from the last public commit; so the correct way would be to ensure that the current commit is pushed to a public repository rather than assuming the last public push to be the "current" commit.

Answer (score 1):

> https://github.com/okohll/agileBase/commits/3ced14ef1004287b55c21d384447c21cb58edfa6 returns a 404 not found error.

In general, the URL is `http://github.com/<user>/<project>/commit/<sha1>`, i.e. a singular `commit`

> I want to find the commit hash that will link to the last commit in github's web interface.

You don’t need to pull that out of your repository first, you can just link to `HEAD` on GitHub: https://github.com/okohll/agileBase/commit/HEAD

If you still want to find out what the current commit is you have in your GitHub repository, you can simply use the log for the remote branch, i.e. `origin/master`:

```
git log -1 origin/master
```

This however requires that you fetched from the remote repository recently as it will only check what you have in your local repository.

Other than that, the only option option left would be to check GitHub directly to get the current hash, possibly with the GitHub API.

Comment: Yes, but I want the last commit ID at the time the script was run, not the current HEAD

Comment: Thanks, Noufal Ibrahim just gave the same answer

Comment: I would try to avoid using the API. It will tie your setup to github and you cannot move to another setup. Best stick with pure git.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim: If the requirement is to get the URL to GitHub showing the current commit as the time of running the script, then I would think relying on GitHub there wouldn’t be a problem at all.